# How precisely do we know the van der Waals radius of hydrogen?

Tags: atomic-physics, measurements

I've found several sources that say the **van der Waals** radius of hydrogen is $120 pm$.

- How precisely do we know this number?
- What order of magnitude is the error on this measurement?

Comment: You can find several different values online, ranging from $100\ \mathrm{pm}$ to $200\ \mathrm{pm}$. Therefore, I'd say $r_W=150\pm50\ \mathrm{pm}$. The reason for these different values found online is discussed in, eg, Wikipedia's [Van der Waals radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_radius): "*...different tables will often have different values for the van der Waals radius of the same atom. Indeed, there is no reason to assume that the van der Waals radius is a fixed property of the atom in all circumstances...*"

Comment: It's just a fuzzy concept. Hence the fuzzy values.